# Want to play background video continuously between two screens

Tags: flutter

i want to play a vid on background on signin page and want that when i click button otp page (or widget appears instead of signIn). Basically i want the video to run contiously any idea how to do that ?

currently i'm maintaining a seperate boolean for that and change content inside build function based on that, but using setstate isn't recommended in riverpod any help?

```
class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final _pinController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    _pinController.dispose();
  }

  bool _isOtp = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final otpContent = Column(
      children: [
        Gap(10.h),
        Text(
          "Enter OTP",
          style: TextStyles.title,
        ),
        Gap(20.h),
        Pinput(
          controller: _pinController,
          length: 4,
        ),
        Gap(20.h),
        ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFF005B),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.r),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () {}, //TODO: To add OTP verification logic
          child: Text(
            "Verify OTP",
            style: TextStyles.subTitle,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
    final loginContent = Column(
      children: [
        Gap(10.h),
        AuthInput(
          controller: _emailController,
          hintText: 'Email/Username',
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        ),
        Gap(20.h),
        AuthInput(
          controller: _passwordController,
          hintText: 'Password',
          inputVisible: false,
        ),
        Gap(20.h),
        ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFF005B),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.r),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _isOtp = true;
            });
          }, //TODO: To add signin logic
          child: Text(
            "Let's Go",
            style: TextStyles.subTitle,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );

    return VideoBackground(
      mainContent:
          SignInCommon(mainLoginContent: _isOtp ? otpContent : loginContent),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share whole code with imports and pubspec.yaml file

Comment: please refer to this repo https://github.com/Fluttery-Dev/Fad

Comment: i tried sing pageview but it dosen't display anything,, but if i remove signUpCommon it does :(

Comment: I have configured your project in my local machine but can you tell me how to produce your error in simpler manor like can you tell me the steps what you want to achieve.

Comment: i solved that issue by myself :). used pageview. My basic que was how can i do my signUp process on foreground while a vid plays in background

Comment: Okay so put your comment as an answer so anybody can quickly get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved that issue by myself :). used pageview